# quasar SPA build produces blank page with Node.js both locally and globally

Tags: node.js, build, quasar

I just built my app with quasar CLI.
This is my quasar info:
[image]

I made a regular spa build knowing that it’s not be sitting directly in root folder on the server, so I changed publicPath:
[image]

Server-side static frontpage files are served OK for the main page and the main page has a link pointing to http://localhost:3000/application which produces blank page with this error:
[image]
[image]

Elements tab looks skim, #q-app does not have any content:
[image]

Network connections with 30x status:
[image]

What am I missing? Could it be related to build itself or is it something in my node-server?
Github said something about lazy-loaded components and dynamic-import-node plugin, so I added it before build:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through script tags in the DOM just to see that their source attributes where all absolute, so I changed them to relative paths by modifying quasar.conf like this:

publicPath: '/application'

That's all it took to make it work :)